# Search Sth in VS2012 that is not commented

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I want to find all `_0` in my code in `VS 2012` Environment, but not in comments :(

Is there a way to delete all comments? (ofcourse just for search and find `_0`)

Comment: **if** all of the comments in your solution are single line comments (`//`) rather than multi-line comments (`/*`...`*/`), or you can tolerate matches in multi-line comments, then you might be able to do it with regex. Otherwise, I think not.

Comment: Why are you using `*` after the `0` then?

Comment: I try to use regex but i couldn't write the correct expression

Comment: your right , it's no need , and         (~(^//))*_0         , find all        _0        too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to only *not* match within single-line comments, then a regular expression with a negative lookbehind can be used:

```
(?<!//.*)_0
```

That is, it matches any occurrence of `_0`, provided that there isn't a `//` (followed by any number of characters) before it.

Comment: whats regular expression for end of line?

Comment: @MohammadIzady - I'm not sure what you're asking, exactly. `\n` matches a newline. `$` matches the end of a line, `.` matches anything other than a newline (if the regex engine isn't working in some special multiline mode)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm trying to find all-of-comment-lines and replace with whitespace for deleting the commetnts. I've tried \/\/\n but its not work. also \/\/$ and \/\/. not work too.